# Test dotnet specifically via the .NET framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, dotnet-test

I have a dotnet project and some unit tests.

When I run: `dotnet test` it actually tests the unit tests using the .NET Core App, but I also do want to test against .NET framework as well.

Is there any way I can specifically target the `dotnet test` to be able to test via the .NET framework?

Comment: have a look on `-f|--framework <FRAMEWORK>`

Comment: Create a .NET Framework test project within your solution.